# How to create a verticle cascading menus in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part, cascading

Can anybody suggest a code to create a verticle cascading dropdown lists in sharepoint using content editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to create menus as you like

Please check the following [link](https://iprignano.github.io/tendina/#examples)

Please let me know in case of any query

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query